# How to share an link on facebook web messenger instead of messenger app

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-messenger

I had tried this

```
<a href="http://m.me/?share=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F" target="_blank" class="fbmsg text-capitalize"><i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger"></i></a>
```

It opens facebook web messenger but not able to share link to my friends.
I need it to be work same as it works in messenger app.

```
<a href="fb-messenger://share/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F" target="_blank" class="fbmsg text-capitalize"><i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger"></i></a>
```

Comment: did you try sharer.php too? or FB.ui share?

Comment: I have not tried, but can we able to share on facebook web messenger using sharper.php or FB.ui. I have no idea regarding how to use sharper.php or FB.ui can you please help me out @luschn

Comment: try it then, with some help from google and the official docs. FB.ui is documented well, and you will find a lot of results for sharer.php too.